# .charAt() returning nullpointerexception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, charat

I've written a small program where I have a two dimensional array with String names. In a nested for loop I check for the first character in each element of the array. If the first character is 'A' || 'E' || 'I' || 'O' || 'U', I write that element into a file with FileWriter. However, every time I try to compile the program I get NullPointerException. This is the code:

FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("imena.txt");

```
String polje[][] = new String[5][5];
polje[0][0] = "Janez";
polje[0][1] = "Tine";
polje[0][2] = "Miha";
polje[0][3] = "Klemen";
polje[0][4] = "Jure";

polje[1][0] = "Tone";
polje[1][1] = "Andrej";
polje[1][2] = "Janko";
polje[1][3] = "Nejc";
polje[1][4] = "Erik";

for(int i = 0; i < polje.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < polje[0].length; j++) {
        if(polje[i][j].charAt(0) == 'A') {
            fw.write(polje[i][j] + '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the if to `if(polje[1][1].charAt(0) == 'A')` it runs perfectly fine, but I want to iterate over all of the elements in the array. Any help would be most appreciated.

As it turns out, I forgot to initialize all of the elements in my array. I can't believe I couldn't see the problem myself. :)

Thanks for the help, everyone! ;)

Comment: Your second loop might be more safely coded as: `for(int j = 0; j < polje[i].length; j++)`.  Also have you considered using a `List<List<String>>` instead of `String[][]`?

Answer (score 3):

You've only initialized as far as `polje[1][...]`. So when `i` is 2 (and `j` is anything), `polje[i][j]` will be null... and when you dereference it by calling `charAt(0)`, you'll get the exception.

Note that this sort of error can be avoided using `List` instead of arrays, where the size grows dynamically. You could even mix the two:

```
List<String[]> polje = new ArrayList<>();
polje.add(new String[] { "Janez", "Tine", ... };
polje.add(new String[] { "Tone", "Andrej", ... };

for (String[] array : polje) {
    for (String item : array) {
        // This way you'll handle empty strings, too
        if (item.startsWith("A")) {
            fw.write(item + '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `new String[2][5];` in your example. With `[5][5]`, you're initializing a 5*5 matrix with null values.

Another solution could be to simply add a not-null condition:

`polje[i][j] != null && polje[i][j].charAt(0) == 'A'`

Answer (score 0):

you only init polje[0] and polje[1], NPE happens when you hit polje[3][0]